# for loop through a list of data frames and save results in new data frame

Tags: r

I want to fetch some values out of a list of data frames and save the results in a new data frame. This is how my code looks:

```
for (i in 1:length(covpatient)){

    a <- names(covpatient[i])
    b <- sum(covpatient[[i]]$cov == 0)
    c <- sum(covpatient[[i]]$cov > 0 & covpatient[[i]]$cov <= 40)
    d <- sum(covpatient[[i]]$cov > 40 & covpatient[[i]]$cov <= 100)
    e <- sum(covpatient[[i]]$cov > 100)
    summary <- c(a,b,c,d,e)
```

}

So for every dataframe in the list covpatient, I want to create a summary variable which consists of 5 elements (a,b,c,d,e). Then I want to make a new data.frame which stores all summary values (5 columns & i rows).

Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `lapply` with `rbind` and then call `as.data.frame`. Since there is no data to play with, I'll give the general idea.

```
o <- lapply(1:length(covpatient), function(i) {
    a <- names(covpatient[i])
    b <- sum(covpatient[[i]]$cov == 0)
    c <- sum(covpatient[[i]]$cov > 0 & covpatient[[i]]$cov <= 40)
    d <- sum(covpatient[[i]]$cov > 40 & covpatient[[i]]$cov <= 100)
    e <- sum(covpatient[[i]]$cov > 100)
    c(a,b,c,d,e)
})
out <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, o))
```

Comment: Yes, that I understand. But when I try to run it, it says: "Error unexpected symbol in: " out"

Comment: Arun has the exact answer to your question.  Using 'lapply' over the set and then binding will do what you want.  I have a feeling, though, that this could be done more simply by backing up a few steps and arranging your data differently.  This feels like something that should be done with an aggregation package like 'plyr', 'data.table', or even 'SPARQL'.